# How to check fluentvalidation isnull or isempty rule for a property in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I made some `HtmlHelper` where I was checking for the `IsRequired` attribute in the `ModelMetadata`. 
Depending on this, I changed the font of the label for the `ViewModel` propery to bold or add an asterisk or whatever.
Then I added the `fluentvalidation` package, which is very nice to use. The downside is, that I don't know how to check if the property has validation for `isNull` or `isEmpty` (which would indicate me the same as the `isRequired` attribute).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29780238/571203 here is an answer.

Comment: @EvgenyLevin: Thank you for your hint. This could be a possibility, but with the use of Javascript on the client. I was looking for a solution in my HtmlHelper.